# How to count a filed with specific condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

| date | train | condition1 | condition2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | train1 | 0 | false |
| 2 | train2 | 1 | true |
| 1 | train3 | 1 | true |
| 1 | train4 | 5 | false |

I want to create a table to count the trains

1. group by date
2. count by conditions

| date | train count | condition1 > 0 | condition2 is true | condition1 > 0 and condition2 is false |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

How can I achieve so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just conditional aggregation:

```
select date, count(*) as cnt_train,
       sum(condition1 > 0) as cnt_condition1,
       sum(condition2) as cnt_condition2
from t
group by date;
```

EDIT:

This uses the MySQL extension that treats boolean values as numbers in a number context, with `1` for true and `0` for false.  This works for any boolean expression, so you can use more complex ones, such as:

```
       sum(condition1 > 0 and condition2) as cnt_condition1_and_condition2
```

Comment: how about joint condition (condition1 > 0 and condition2 is true)

Comment: Use `and` for combining the condition in the aggregate function.